# how to change the default partial file name for fields_forr?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I am using nested_form_for to update phone_number associated with a contact_info object.

```
<%= nested_form_for @contact_info do |f| %>

  <%= f.fields_for :phone_numbers %>
  <%#= render :partial => "phone_numbers/form", :locals =>{ :b => g } %>


  <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add a phone number", :phone_numbers %></p>

<% end %>
```

As shown above, I tried to override the partial using a render statement. But it didn't work. What would be the standard way to override the contact_info_fields.html.erb partial?

Answer (score 2):

You need to supply the `render` statement in a block passed to `fields_for`. Like this:

```
<%= f.fields_for :phone_numbers do |phone_f| %>
  <%= render :partial => "phone_numbers/form" %>
<% end %>
```

I'm not sure what your `locals` or `link_to_add` are doing, so I can't easily comment on how those should be adjusted.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed that nested_form_for doesn't work well with rails 3.1.1. The link_to_add is part of the nested_form_for component. So I am waiting for that to be resolved first. I will probably end up following the railscast instruction on how to build a nested form since that seems to be the only stable way now.